# Can I extend custom things (like only nav drawer) from one activity to another one?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activities: SplashActivity and MainActivity. I make a drawer menu in MainActivity, and include a content.xml in there.

I want to import the drawer menu to all my activities that I make in the future.

I make a new activity like IntroActivity and extend it. Actually, I don't want to see content.xml that is included in MainActivity in IntroActivity and only want to see the drawer and in IntroActivity.

This is my mainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Typeface textfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/B Roya_YasDL.com.ttf");
        tv.setTypeface(textfont);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.a1);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_more_vert_black_24dp);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.a2);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                item.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                switch (item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.intro:
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;
                }



                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.khat) {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }

            else {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somthing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void onBackPressed(){
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }else {super.onBackPressed();}

    }
}
```

This is my IntroActivity:

```
public class IntroActivity extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro2);
    }
}
```

Can I do something to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Your `IntroActivity` should not extend your `MainActivity` because `IntroActivity` **IS NOT** a `MainActivity` type object.

To have the navigation drawer functionality into one or more activities you should create an abstract activity class, `NavigationDrawerActivity`, and move all the code for the navigation drawer from `MainActivity` there.
 Then make `IntroActivity` and `MainActivity` extend `NavigationDrawerActivity`.

This way both your activities will have the navigation drawer functionality and won't share them unnecessarily, like the `content.xml` layout.

Comment: thanks . and can u guide me how can I create abstract class.
sorry if my question is awkwardly. but, it's one of the problems in self-study